# i am working on video watermarking in dwt domain

Tags: matlab, video-processing

i want to convert frames to a video which can be played in vlc player or media player. Without using the command videowriter. can anyone suggest  me the technique to do the same.

Comment: A good alternative is to load your stack in ImageJ and save it to avi.

Comment: Why don't you want to use `videowriter`? Don't you want to use MATLAB at all?

Comment: my matlab version is 10 a . in that there is no videowriter. if i use videowriter it shows undefined char. so that is the reason i want to use some other technnique.

Comment: i am reading 10 frames now. and used videowriter after my process but the frames are 55 instead of 10. why so?